# Are double quotes supported in a JSON string?

Tags: javascript, json

When I escape double quotes via `\"` in a JSON string the parser fails.  However, when I use `JSON.stringify` it is capable of properly escaping the string somehow.

I suspect that I'm not escaping the double quotes properly.  Look to the code for more detail.

```js
var data = {
  "singleQuoteHtml": "<span class='qwer'>content</span>",
  "doubleQuoteHtml": "<span class=\"qwer\">content</span>",
  "singleQuote": "'hi'",
  "doubleQuote": "\"hi\""
};

var dataString = '{"singleQuoteHtml": "<span class=\'qwer\'>content</span>",'
  + '"doubleQuoteHtml": "<span class=\"qwer\">content</span>",'
  + '"singleQuote": "\'hi\'",'
  + '"doubleQuote": "\"hi\"'
  + '}';



function Parse()
{
  //Stringify is capable of creating single quotes and double quotes
  console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)));
  
  //When I escape double quotes myself the parser fails
  //Uncomment to see failure
  //console.log(JSON.parse(dataString));
}
```

```html
<button onclick="Parse();">Parse JSON </button>
```

Comment: Why do you want to create the `dataString` using string concatenation at all? Why don't you create a regular JavaScript Object and then use `JSON.stringify()` to create the `dataString`, that will solve many problems that could occur with escaping.

Comment: The actual code is Java based. And the data being made available to me is a plain old string, not a Java object.  So I'm not sure how to stringify with these constraints in Java. But you may be right. Probably less headache once it's figured out.

Comment: In Java you can avoid having to manually escape strings by adding a `String` property a a `TestClass` and deserializing `TestClass` via `String jsonRawString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(testObject)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string literal `'... "\"hi\""...'` evaluates to `""hi""`, without backslashes.

The backslashes are swallowed as escape sequences by the string literal.

You need to escape your backslashes as `\\` to put actual backslashes in your string.